# Slim framework + nginx = issues with path

Tags: php, nginx, slim

I've tried literally every suggestion on the web and it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using slim framework to create REST services, and I call them in this format:

```
 http://localhost:8080/myProject/resources/myapp.php/test/
```

and in myapp.php I have this defined:

```
$app->get('/test/', ...
```

when I used xampp this of course worked, but when I migrated to nginx, I get the 404 error.

On the official page they say I should add this to location:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

I've changed the nginx.conf accordingly:

```
    location / {
        root   html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

I still get the 'No input file specified.' 404 error.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Kiitos Mika.... that worked perfectly.
I had several problems with my routes on production server using nginx. It seemed for me only the subfolders were not working in GET when there were variables, all were getting 404.

Adding the query_string fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from URL it appears you are not using index.php, but myapp.php):

`try_files $uri $uri/ /myapp.php?$args;`

Comment: I changed index.php to myapp.php and it doesn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Check webserver error log. Might have more information.

Answer (score 0):

The following in nginx.conf is known to work.

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`